# WebFlux: Only one item arriving at the backend

Tags: spring-webflux

On the backend im doing:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/products", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public void saveProducts(@Valid @RequestBody Flux<Product> products) {
    products.subscribe(product -> log.info("product: " + product.toString()));
}
```

And on the frontend im calling this using:

```
this.targetWebClient
            .post()
            .uri(productUri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .body(this.sourceWebClient
                    .get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(this.sourceEndpoint + "/id")
                            .queryParam("date", date)
                            .build())
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(Product.class), Product.class)
            .exchange()
            .subscribe();
```

What happens now is that I have 472 products which need to get saved but only one of them is actually saving. The stream closes after the first and I cant find out why.

If I do:

```
...
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(Void.class);
```

instead, the request isnt even arriving at the backend.

I also tried fix amount of elements:

```
.body(Flux.just(new Product("123"), new Product("321")...
```

And with that also only the first arrived.

**EDIT**

I changed the code:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/products", consumes = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<Void> saveProducts(@Valid @RequestBody Flux<Product> products) {
    products.subscribe(product -> this.service.saveProduct(product));

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

and:

```
this.targetWebClient
            .post()
            .uri(productUri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .body(this.sourceWebClient
                    .get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(this.sourceEndpoint + "/id")
                            .queryParam("date", date)
                            .build())
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(Product.class), Product.class)
            .exchange()
            .block();
```

That led to the behaviour that one product was saved twice (because the backend endpoint was called twice) but again only just one item. And also we got an error on the frontend side:

```
IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

Same for:

```
...
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(Void.class)
.subscribe();
```

Doing the following:

```
this.targetWebClient
            .post()
            .uri(productUri)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
            .body(this.sourceWebClient
                    .get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(this.sourceEndpoint + "/id")
                            .queryParam("date", date)
                            .build())
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(Product.class), Product.class)
            .retrieve();
```

Leads to the behaviour that the backend again isnt called at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Reactor documentation [does say that nothing happens until you subscribe](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_from_imperative_to_reactive_programming), but it doesn't mean you should subscribe in your Spring WebFlux code.

Here are a few rules you should follow in Spring WebFlux:

- If you need to do something in a reactive fashion, the return type of your method should be `Mono` or `Flux`
- Within a method returning a reactive typoe, you should never call `block` or `subscribe`, `toIterable`, or any other method that doesn't return a reactive type itself
- You should never do I/O-related in side-effects `DoOnXYZ` operators, as they're not meant for that and this will cause issues at runtime

In your case, your backend should use a reactive repository to save your data and should look like:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/products", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<Void> saveProducts(@Valid @RequestBody Flux<Product> products) {
    return productRepository.saveAll(products).then();
}
```

In this case, the `Mono<Void>` return type means that your controller won't return anything as a response body but will signal still when it's done processing the request. This might explain why you're seeing that behavior - by the time the controller is done processing the request, all products are not saved in the database.

Also, remember the rules noted above. Depending on where your `targetWebClient` is used, calling `.subscribe();` on it might not be the solution. If it's a test method that returns `void`, you might want to call `block` on it and get the result to test assertions on it. If this is a component method, then you should probably return a `Publisher` type as a return value.

**EDIT:**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/products", consumes = 
MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<Void> saveProducts(@Valid @RequestBody Flux<Product> products) {
    products.subscribe(product -> this.service.saveProduct(product));

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

Doing this isn't right:

- calling subscribe decouples the processing of the request/response from that `saveProduct` operation. It's like starting that processing in a different executor.
- returning `Mono.empty()` signals Spring WebFlux that you're done right away with the request processing. So Spring WebFlux will close and clean the request/response resources; but your `saveProduct` process is still running and won't be able to read from the request since Spring WebFlux closed and cleaned it.

As suggested in the comments, you can [wrap blocking operations with Reactor](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) (even though it's not advised and you may encounter performance issues) and make sure that you're connecting all the operations in a single reactive pipeline.

Comment: Edited my post. I cant find the correct methods to call to get the expected behaviour.

Comment: that's because you're still using subscribe. Could you provide some information about this service you're using? Is that a Spring Data repository?

Comment: no. we cant use spring data since for our data layer there is no reactive spring data repo. Without the subscribe nothing happens. The `service` used there is basically putting the results into an apache ignite cache.

Comment: using blocking operations is not advised. If you really need to, you can still wrap those operations like this: http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Comment: I replaced the service call with a simple logout in the subscribe. Same results.

Comment: At that point, I think you should read a bit about the reactive model, as it's really different and can be confusing at first. See the Reactor ref docs on that: http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_from_imperative_to_reactive_programming and an intro from a Servlet point of view: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dp_aJh-akkU

Comment: Yes. We are waiting for the reacitve implementation for ignite. It is on the roadmap. But the behaviour still makes no sense to me since running the frontend locally and the backend services deployed on our servers works perfectly as I would expect it. But having the frontend on the same server leads to these issues.